# Вывести максимально число return

Tags: java, return

Ошибка `maxNumber cannot be resolved to a variable`.
Сделайте функцию, возвращающую максимум из трех чисел. Три числа идут параметрами, возвращается через `return` максимальное из них. В `main` вызовите эту функцию для разных входных параметров и проверьте, правильно ли она работает.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите первое число: ");
    Integer one = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите второе число: ");
    Integer two = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Введите третье число: ");
    Integer three = scanner.nextInt();


maxValues(one, two, three);
System.out.println("Максимальное число - " + maxNumber);
  }

  public static Integer maxValues (int a, int b, int c) {
    int maxNumber = 0;
    if(a>=b && a>=c) {
      maxNumber = a;
    }
    else if(b>=a && b>=c) {
      maxNumber = b;
    } else {
      maxNumber = c;  
    }
    return maxNumber;
  }
}
```

Не понимаю почему `return` не возвращает значение в

```
System.out.println("Максимальное число - " + maxNumber)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
maxValues(one, two, three);
System.out.println("Максимальное число - " + maxNumber);
```

А откуда у вас в `main` возьмётся переменная `maxNumber`? Она есть только внутри функции `maxValues`. Нужно завести переменную в `main` и присвоить ей результат работы функции:

```java
int maxNumber = maxValues(one, two, three);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
System.out.println("Максимальное число - " + maxNumber);
```